# Shannon's entropy on FTIR data

Tags: entropy

I want to calculate shannon's entropy on a ftir data. I have used two approaches and i get two different entropy value.
the second code, where i have removed the backgroud using clustering and calcualted entropy. however, the entropy before removing Bg is still way too different.
Please share your opinion and guidance.

```
import scipy.io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Path to your .mat file
mat_file_path = 'structure1.mat'

# Load the .mat file
mat_data = scipy.io.loadmat(mat_file_path)

# Extract wavenumbers
wavenumbers = mat_data['wavenumbers'].squeeze()

# Extract intensity data
intensity_data = mat_data['spcImage']

# Select a specific position in the image to plot
position = (100, 100)
intensity_at_position = intensity_data[position[0], position[1], :]

# Plot the spectral data
plt.plot(wavenumbers, intensity_at_position)
plt.xlabel('Wavenumber')
plt.ylabel('Intensity')
plt.title('Spectral Data at Position (100, 100)')
plt.show()

# Calculate probability distribution
prob_distribution = average_spectra / np.sum(average_spectra)

# Calculate entropy
entropy = -np.sum(prob_distribution * np.log2(prob_distribution + 1e-10))
print("Shannon's Entropy:", entropy)
```

The spectral image is attached here.
Result : Shannon's Entropy: 6.257635131501756

```
import os
import scipy.io
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

# Define the cluster_k function
def cluster_k(p, k=2, init='k-means++', max_iter=300):
    # Reshape 3D array to 2D for clustering
    data_to_cluster = p.reshape(-1, p.shape[2]) if len(p.shape) == 3 else p
    # Perform K-Means clustering
    model = KMeans(n_clusters=k, init=init, n_init=10, max_iter=max_iter).fit(data_to_cluster)
    # Obtain labels and reshape if original data was 3D
    labels = model.labels_.reshape(p.shape[0], p.shape[1]) if len(p.shape) == 3 else model.labels_
    return model, labels

# Define Shannon's entropy calculation function
def shannons_entropy(data):
    data_flatten = data.flatten()
    data_flatten_no_nan = data_flatten[~np.isnan(data_flatten)]
    p_data = np.bincount(data_flatten_no_nan.astype(int)) / len(data_flatten_no_nan)
    entropy = -np.sum(p_data * np.log2(p_data + 1e-10))
    return entropy

# Define a function to extract patient number from file name
def extract_patient_number(filename):
    # Extract the part before the first underscore and convert to float
    return float(filename.split('_')[0])

# Path to the directory containing .mat files
mat_dir_path = 'filenames.mat'

# List all .mat files in the directory
mat_files = [f for f in os.listdir(mat_dir_path) if f.endswith('.mat')]

# List to store entropy values for each file
entropy_list = []

# Loop through each .mat file
for mat_file in mat_files:
    try:
        # Load the .mat file
        mat_data = scipy.io.loadmat(os.path.join(mat_dir_path, mat_file))

        # Extract intensity data
        intensity_data = mat_data['spcImage']

        # Apply clustering to remove background
        model, mask = cluster_k(intensity_data, k=2)
        background_label = np.argmin(np.sum(model.cluster_centers_, axis=1))
        signal_label = 1 - background_label
        signal_mask = (mask == signal_label)
        intensity_data_no_background = np.where(signal_mask[..., np.newaxis], intensity_data, np.nan)

        # Calculate Shannon's entropy after removing the background
        entropy = shannons_entropy(intensity_data_no_background)

        # Extract patient number from the file name
        patient_number = extract_patient_number(mat_file)

        # Append a tuple with all three pieces of data
        entropy_list.append((mat_file, patient_number, entropy))

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred with file {mat_file}: {e}")
        continue  # Continue with the next file

# Convert list to DataFrame
entropy_df = pd.DataFrame(entropy_list, columns=['FileName', 'PatientNumber', 'Shannon_Entropy'])

# Save entropy values as CSV
csv_output_path = '/content/drive/Shareddrives/CHEMPREDICT-DL/Rahul_Code/entropy_values.csv'
entropy_df.to_csv(csv_output_path, index=False)

print(f"Processed {len(entropy_list)} files. Results are saved to {csv_output_path}")
```

Result: Result : Shannon's Entropy: 0.003
Thank you

I tried shannon's entropy on a spectral data. I was expecting a result between 0 and 1. The two different codes which I have tried give two different result. I am curious to know if this apporoach is right.

Comment: The maximum for Shannon's entropy in these sorts of applications with N bins all equally populated is log(N) = -N*(log(1/N)/N). It isn't clear to me how many bins you actually have in your probability distribution - is it 8bit, 12bit or 16bit intensity data? On the flip side if most bins are empty and just one bin has all of the counts in it is 0 =1*log(1). The first number and way of doing it looks about right to me although what Shannon entropy means when applied to ftir spectral data is much less clear to me.

Comment: Here, as we do not provide the bit, the intensity value present in the spectral data will be used. 
I realize, in the first code, the entropy is calculated for particular position and hence high entropy. The second code give decent entropy value but still i want to know if i am missing something. 
thank you for your comment